# HTTP user-agent of iOS SocialUIService?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-headers, facebook-opengraph, uiactivityviewcontroller

When using the native iOS share dialog `UIActivityViewController` inside you own App and starting to share a link via the Facebook icon a `SocialUIService` is in the background crawling the link/website for additional information.

What HTTP user-agent has this `SocialUIService` service?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, when the `SocialUIService` fetches the link in the background, the user agent is:

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B440`

Where if you were to click on the link in Safari, it would look like this:

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4`

Notice the two missing pieces are `Version/8.0` and `Safari/600.1.4`